# Query fails to execute after converting a column from Varchar2 to CLOB

Tags: oracle11g, clob

I have a oracle query

```
select id from (
    select ID, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by LATEST_RECEIPT order by ID) rownumber
    from Table
    where LATEST_RECEIPT in 
    (
        select LATEST_RECEIPT from Table 
        group by LATEST_RECEIPT
        having COUNT(1) > 1
    )
) t
where rownumber <> 1;
```

The data type of LATEST_RECEIPT was earlier varchar2(4000) and this query worked fine. Since the length of the column needs to be extended i modified it to CLOB, after which this fails. Could anyone help me fix this issue or provide a work around?

Comment: What error is thrown?

Comment: ORA00932- inconsistent data type- expected : got clob

Comment: That's one of the drawbacks on using CLOB/BLOB, they can't be used fo indexes and then also not for `GROUP BY`and other agregate functions. I think you will have to convert it back into a `VARCHAR(much-longer)`data type

Comment: I have data which has length > 4000.  But max size of varchar2 in oracle is 4000. So, we switched to CLOB

Comment: Then this is a real problem of your DBMS and the use case you have. Do you realy need to group by the whole `LAST_RECEIPT` text? (If yes, then you probably would need to add another column with a hash key of the text and then use this for the group by condition)

Comment: Thanks much for your response!!

Answer (score 1):

You can change your inner query to look for other rows with the same `last_receipt` value but a different ID (assuming ID is unique); if another row exists then that is equivalent to your count returning greater than one. But you can't simply test two CLOB values for equality, you need to use `dbms_lob.compare`:

```
select ID
from your_table t1
where exists (
    select null from your_table t2
    where dbms_lob.compare(t2.LATEST_RECEIPT, t1.LATEST_RECEIPT) = 0
    and t2.ID != t1.ID
    -- or if ID isn't unique: and t2.ROWID != t1.ROWID
);
```

Applying the row number filter is tricker, as you also can't use a CLOB in the analytic `partition by` clause. As André Schild suggested, you can use a hash; here passing the integer value 3, which is the equivalent of `dbms_crypto.hash_sh1` (though in theory that could change in a future release!):

```
select id from (
    select ID, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by dbms_crypto.hash(LATEST_RECEIPT, 3)
        order by ID) rownumber
    from your_table t1
    where exists (
        select null from your_table t2
        where dbms_lob.compare(t2.LATEST_RECEIPT, t1.LATEST_RECEIPT) = 0
        and t2.ID != t1.ID
        -- or if ID isn't unique: and t2.ROWID != t1.ROWID
    )
)
where rownumber > 1;
```

It is of course possible to get a hash collision, and if that happened - you had two `latest_receipt` values which both appeared more than once and both hashed to the same value - then you could get too many rows back. That seems pretty unlikely, but it's something to consider.

So rather than ordering you can only look for rows which have the same `lastest_receipt` and a lower ID:

```
select ID
from your_table t1
where exists (
    select null from your_table t2
    where dbms_lob.compare(t2.LATEST_RECEIPT, t1.LATEST_RECEIPT) = 0
    and t2.ID < t1.ID
);
```

---

Again that assumes ID is unique. If it isn't then you could still use `rowid` instead, but you would have less control over which rows were found - the lowest `rowid` isn't necessarily the lowest ID. Presumably you're using this to dine rows to delete. If you actually don't mind which row you keep and which you delete then you could still do:

```
and t2.ROWID < t1.ROWID
```

But since you are currently ordering that probably isn't acceptable, and hashing might be preferable, despite the small risk.